# Using a string argument to represent an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have the following code:

```
TextBox txtUsername = new TextBox();
void setEnabled(string str, bool enable)
{
    // use str to find the TextBox object
    // str.Enabled = enable;
}
```

Is this kinda thing even possible?

I want to be passing in 'Username' and then be prepending it with 'txt'.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.Net cotrols try [Control.FindControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

and for winforms use [Controls.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set the `Name`-Property, then you can access it via it's owner:

```
this.Controls.Item(str).Enabled = enabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store all your text fields in a dictionary with an identifier:

```
Dictionary<string,TextBox> index = new Dictionary<string,TextBox>();
index.add("Username",txtUsername);

void setEnabled(string str, bool enable)
{
    index[str].Enabled = enable;
}
```

Comment: nice insight, thanks, but it seems that FindControl is the built-in way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the page into the function, otherwise in what context is the function going to search for the control? The you can use Page,FindControl() method to find the control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
   TextBox txtUsername = new TextBox();
   txtUsername.Name = "txtUsername ";



  void SetEnable(string str, bool enable)
  {
    this.Controls.Item("txt" + str).Enabled = enabled;
  }
```

Little modification from "Bobby" answer.